# Mangoosastic Full Text Search via Telegram Bot

Tags: javascript, full-text-search, mongoosastic

I have a `msg.text` variable Incomming from Telegram Bot, `msg.text` is = My Schema name, How Should I get names Contain words entered by the user ?

**schema:**

```
const parentSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    name: String,
});
parentSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    hosts: [
        'localhost:9200'
    ]
});
const Mq = mongoose.model('Mq', parentSchema);

module.exports = Mq;
```

**Code:**

```
bot.onText(/\/search/, (msg) => {
// mangoosastic search Code
});
```

Forexample in my db I have {`rock`, `book`, `pre rock`, `Cat`, `rock after`, and `pre rock after`}
and user `msg.txt` = `ro` How Should I get and console.log Words Contain `ro`in node.js Project:

**I need to get:**
`rock`
`pre rock`
`rock after`
`pre rock after`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Problem Solved With Native MongoDB regex**

```
parentSchema.index({ name: 'text' });
    Mq.find(
        { "name": { "$regex": "ro", "$options": "i" } },
        function(err,docs) { 
        } 
    );
```